# when i run "nodemon app.js" it works fine, but when i run "npm run dev" I get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, nodemon

I have nodemon installed both globally and on my project, when i run `nodemon app.js` it works fine, but when i run `npm run dev` because of i have edited my `package.json` file to have this in my scripts `dev`: `nodemon app.js` it returns an error.

Specifically this:

> 'EXPRESSJS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file. node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\moyoa\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Node.js v18.13.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my directory, it identified one of my folders as a command and tried to locate it.

To fix this change your directory if you come across this type of issue.
Given nodemon is already correctly installed globally or in your current

And be careful with how your name the folder destination you use to code.

In case of future issues